# Restrict Subscription privilege for sign-up in WSO2 API manager store

Tags: api, wso2, authorization, roles, wso2-api-manager

The WSO2 api manager store  allows user to sign up and by default they have privileges to subscribe to api's. We would like to restrict the privilege for sign up users to just login and view available API's. We figured out one of the ways is to create a role with just "login" privilege and use it as default privilege for  sign-up users.How can this be done?  .The API documentation specifies to edit the following section in `<APIM_HOME>/repository/conf/api-manager.xml` .

```
<SelfSignUp>
     <Enabled>true</Enabled>
     <SubscriberRoleName>NewSubscriber</SubscriberRoleName>
     <CreateSubscriberRole>true</CreateSubscriberRole>
</SelfSignUp>
```

However there is no such section in api-manager.xml file and doesn't seem to work when added.Has anybody done it or has any ideas

Answer (score 0):

It can not be configured in api-manager.xml file. The API Manager [documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM180/Customizing+the+API+Store) says to edit the "sign-up-config.xml" in registry path "/_system/governance/apimgt/applicationdata/sign-up-config". Please refer to the documentation for more details. However note that when you remove API subscriber permission from the self-signup role, self-signup users won't be able to login to the API Store. But by default anyone (anyone who have the access to the store web app) can browse the APIs in the public API store without login.